# JMeter Synthesis Report generates incorrect data

Tags: jmeter

I'm not sure if JMeter Synthesis Report generates incorrect data or I don't understand something about JTL files. The situation is that I run distributed JMeter test in nonGUI mode with command

```
jmeter.bat -n -t my_test.jmx -l my_results.jtl -j info.log -r
```

After test finishes I generate summary report using following command (I have jmeter-plugins-synthesis-2.2.jar in my classpath)

```
JMeterPluginsCMD.bat --tool Reporter --generate-csv summary.csv --input-jtl my_results.jtl --plugin-type SynthesisReport
```

It produces nice report, but I'm not sure if I can trust it. E.g. for one test step which is Transaction controller I see max response time 21720. But when I filter all sample tags containing my step name in JTL file, I see that max value in **t** attribute is 11183. Do I need to add any extra values to **t** value to get real response time?

Comment: Seems everything works fine. Just my script was analyzing only successful samples, but I had few time our errors which generated longer than usually response times.

Answer (score 0):

Synthesis Report should be accurate enough, you can double check it by opening your `my_results.jtl` file using [Aggregate Report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) and/or [Summary Report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Summary_Report)

[Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller/) is summing up **all its children execution time**, so you need to sum up all Transaction Controller's children, not only take the longest sampler response time.

It might also be the case the Transaction Controller is configured to include time taken by [PreProcessors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#preprocessors), [PostProcessors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and [Timers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers) so if you have any of them - the difference may be due to these elements.